# Is it possible to trigger keyboard shortcuts on non-English keyboard input via Dvorak key position?

Tags: macos, keyboard, language

I use Dvorak layout on my macOS and have other keyboard input including Simplified Chinese and Korean. However, to trigger a keyboard shortcut such as Command + w on Korean keyboard, I must use the key position based on QWERTY.

On Dvorak layout, 'w' is typed via the ',' position and ',' is type via 'w'. So in order to close the current window:

- On Dvorak, Command + ,
- On Simplified Chinese, Command + ,
- On Korean, Command + w

This is quite stressful and thus I want to make them consistent. When I'm in Korean input the shortcut opens the preference pane. I didn't check other keyboards but at least Korean keyboard input is based on the QWERTY layout while Chinese is based on Dvorak. Is there any way to make Korean keyboard (and maybe others as well) react based on Dvorak layout?

Comment: You would need to modify the KoreanIM.app to get a Dvorak mapping, or find a 3rd party IM that has this as an option.  Apple's Chinese IM happens to adopt the mapping of the last-used Latin layout.  Japanese has a preference setting you can change.  But Korean is stuck with qwerty I think.

Comment: @TomGewecke What is the 'KoreanIM.app'?

Comment: That's where the Korean input sources are located.  It's in System/Library/Input Methods

Comment: @TomGewecke I see, thanks. It seems too complicated to define the rule as I need to disable the system integration and detect where to modify. Maybe it is easier to apply the custom rules only to Korean input on Karabiner-Element.

Comment: If you are successful with Karabiner, post it as an answer here.